# Is there a way to end a questline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there like a console command to end a questline and have it count in the statistics? I have already tried to find if there was a console command for it but I couldn't find any

Comment: Depends on the questline. Which one are you wanting to end? (There are 5 of them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`completequest <QuestID>` is your solution.

However, you have to know ids of quests so you can simply complete them with this command in order.

Alternatively, you could use `setstage <quest id> <stage value>` to finish all of the quest. However, you will need to figure out the Quest and Stage ID's to do this.

SetStage is recommended since CompleteQuest can cause bugs.